# Dart Pub greater than and less then markdown issue

Tags: dart, markdown, publish

Having an issue with the display of "<" and ">" using markdown's back-tick code syntax in Dart pub? Not sure how to achieve: `Future<bool>`. If I write that as I have done here, it comes out as: `Future&lt;bool&gt;`, as found here: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/functional_behaviour_tree

Have also noticed that where packages were fine before on Pub, it now seems that the markdown is being interpreted differently? The formatting has gone a bit mad and caused some chaos with all of my package readme files and such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with the Dart version of pub.dartlang.org (was Python until recently) https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dartlang-dart/issues/16

Comment: Thanks Gunter, I couldn't find this last night and assumed it to be my own stupidity. There are a few other bits and pieces that worked before that don't now, such as nested lists, stacking line code comments in code block, line breaks in the md file that cause letters to overlap in documentation (really weird) and the default underscore replacement for spaces that automatically gets generated for the md file title from project name now causes an italics effect on the site. I don't know if these have been spotted or not?

Comment: If there aren't open issues in the GitHub repo already please report it.